# Как к извлеченным URL-адресам, найденным на странице в тегах, добавить ' http:/', чтобы использовать их для дальнейшего парсинга

Tags: python, парсер, url

С сайта я извлекла следующие гиперссылки:

- /russia/reg19/
- /russia/reg87/
- /russia/reg29/ и т.д.

Если перейти по этим гиперссылкам, URL-адрес будет такой: http://worldgeo.ru/russia/reg19/
Как мне "прикрутить" вот эту часть "http://worldgeo.ru" к гиперссылке (если это вообще возможно), чтобы продолжить парсить в том же самом скрипте.

Я новичок, прошу Вас попроще )

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: print("http://worldgeo.ru/" + "/russia/reg19/")

Comment: Спасибо,  получилось!